# Red ants entered Amazon Kindle 7 generation

Tags: kindle, amazon

My amazon kindle is of 7th generation. I have found that red ants have entered my kindle through the data transfer slot. How should I get rid of them before they damage my kindle?

Comment: Try to load this ebook http://amzn.to/2oWy4AV ... Sorry guy, just kidding, your question is the funniest I have ever read on this site :)

Comment: Perhaps contact Amazon's Kindle support and ask if they can remotely debug your Kindle.

Comment: I have found a solution. Just blow air through the kindle USB slot using a blower or by mouth. The ants come out like magic....